# How can I call latest products within the WordPress FrontEnd

Tags: php, html, wordpress

During the development stages of creating my 1st WordPress Theme with WooCommerce functionality, from scratch, I have been hard coding all of the relevant content directly into the php files.  Not sure if this is 'standard' with others but was my approach in safeguarding content, should anything happen to the MySql Database.

That said, I am not transferring all relevant content to the FrontEnd of WordPress.  I have started with the index.php file, where I have entered the following code into my index.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ):  
            while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
    ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php 
            endwhile; 
        endif; 
    ?>

<?php get_footer (); ?>
```

Within the content itself, I want to be able to call the latest products published.  I have managed to achieve this by entering the following code into a template file and then calling it in the index.php:

```
<div class="row" id="latest-products">
    <h2 id="latest-products-row"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="latest-products-title">Latest Products</span><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
        <ul class="row-fluid">
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'DESC' );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
            ?>
                        <li class="latest-products">    
                            <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php 
                                    if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
                                    else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; 
                                ?>
                            </a>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <div class="price-row"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="product-price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span><i class="fa fa-cirlce" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                <div class="buy-button"><a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">View/Buy</a></div>
                        </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

For now, I simply just want to call the above code within the FrontEnd of WordPress.  At present, the only way I can do this, is via hard coding which isn't something I wish to achieve.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of where I can start on achieving this?  Eventually, I would like to create an option, within the WordPress Pages/Post, whereby you can select and it opens a Box with options such as 'How many Products you would like to show,' 'Background Colour' etc.  If this is not that much extra work, I would appreciate any pointers to achieve this too.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean here... the code you posted is the correct way to do this...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The code works when hard coded into the index.php file, however I would like this code placed in the frontend of WordPress instead.  Thus being called in the index.php file via `<?php the_content ?>` When I place the above above in the frontend, the coding just appears rather than the actual content.

Comment: You should just be able to copy that code into the index.php file and if you have products entered it should render it out. If it doesn't you have something wrong with your WP installation. If you have that code in an external file, you can use `load_template_part()` to load that code in.

Comment: It works in the index.php file just not in the frontend when I paste the code directly into the WordPress Page.  It just shows the code.

Comment: Right. Because you can't add PHP code to the WYSIWYG editor. That kind of stuff has to be done at the template level.

Comment: Is there a way around this, so that I can dynamically call products 'within' the `the_content`?  From what I can see, from this, I can only call such details before or after the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick research on the WooCommerce shortcodes, you can call this: `[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4"]` and it will show the recent products. Simply paste that into your WYSIWYG editor.

For more information on WooCommerce shortcodes, view this link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: Thanks for this.  Much appreciated.  Is there not a way where I can continue using the PHP approach but through the use of Wysiwyg?  Such as Custom Fields etc?  With the Shortcodes, I feel I have less control over the overall appearances.

Comment: You can create your own shortcode if you'd like... that should be easy enough. Check out the shortcode API: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API Feel free to accept this as the answer if you'd like :)